# Stuck at reading offset/pointer

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, process, offset

I am reading memory of a process like this:

```
int MEM_BATTLESPEED_ADDR = 0x12EC900; // <- this is a static address
int MEM_battleSpeed;
if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,(void *) MEM_BATTLESPEED_ADDR, &MEM_battleSpeed, 4, NULL))   
{
   cout << "MEM_battleSpeed: " << MEM_battleSpeed << "\r\n"; 
}
```

The address is static so it never changes when I restart the application. I can read this without problem. It's all okay.

My problem is, some addresses aren't static. I know the offsets and pointers but I don't know how to read the following:

```
[Info]
$Static   = 0x12BCAC8
$Offset_1 = 0x07F8
$Offset_2 = 0x000C
$Offset_3 = 0x0284
```

How can I read the [Info] value?

Comment: Are the offsets in bytes from $Static?

Comment: Yes, they are 4 bytes. Also, they look like this in C.E: http://i.imgur.com/hSs6K.png

Comment: What do you mean by "they are 4 bytes"? The offsets are much larger than that. Do you mean that the values of $Offset_1, $Offset_2 and $Offset_3 should be interpreted as offsets from the memory address $Static, in multiples of 4 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the offset to the contents of the pointer gives the address that you want:

```
Static   = 0x12BCAC8;
Offset_1 = 0x07F8;

ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,(void *) (Static + Offset_1), &value, 4, NULL);
```

Comment: When I try Static + Offset_1, it automatically prints the decimal value. Would it work, cause I couldn't get it to work yet. Always reads 0.

Comment: I'm only going by the image you posted.  The address of an offset from a pointer is just the sum of the two.  If its not what you want, then your static value is not the real pointer or the offset is not in bytes.